# Lightning process builder with previous version of Salesforce

Tags: process-builder, lightning-experience

To use Lightning process builder do we need to switch our org to lightning experience?

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Process Builder works fine with Salesforce classic.  No need to enable lightning experience for that.

Answer (score 2):

The Lightning Process Builder is a tool that allows you to easily automate business processes using a convenient graphical representation of your process as you build it (It is more advanced version of workflow rules.). Automated processes in the Process Builder consist of:

- Criteria that determine when to execute action groups and
- Immediate and scheduled actions to execute when those criteria are met.

Check out this short video to become more familiar with how the Process Builder works.

https://youtu.be/XgjlPWaElRc

So there is no need to enable Lightning experience it works without lightning experience as well.

Here is screenshot of Lightning process builder

[image]

To more about the process builder go through the [Lightning Process Builder Trailhead module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/business_process_automation/process_builder).